# Ansible: I need to create a playbook to execute the shell script in ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, gitlab, yaml

i need to create an ansible job to execute the shell script which is having arguments for different environments (one playbook which will be applicable to all environments test, QA and prod by providing argument in the command). for example, I need to execute script ABC.sh for which normal command is
sh ABC.sh /105t (for test execution) or sh ABC.sh /105q (for QA execution).
Can someone please help me with the playbook for this? Thanks!!

I tried the below format in YML file in gitlab.

```
-name: execute the script

 tasks:

   name: execute the ABC script
   script: sh script_dir_path/ABC.sh /105t
```

The job ran successfully but it did not trigger the script execution.

Comment: Since you have already achieved parts of your overall goal according your post, is there any specific question? Where do you struggle? Are there error messages or log outputs? In other words, can provide more information and description?

Answer (score 1):

Use the module [*script*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#ansible-builtin-script-module-runs-a-local-script-on-a-remote-node-after-transferring-it). It runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it. For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── script_dir_path
    └── ABC.sh
```

Create a simple script that displays the first argument

```bash
shell> cat script_dir_path/ABC.sh 
echo $1
```

The playbook below runs on all remote hosts. It will transfer the script to the remotes, run it with the argument *arg*, and display the result

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - script:
        cmd: "script_dir_path/ABC.sh {{ arg }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

The playbook works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e arg=/105t

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [script] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  out.stdout: |-
    /105t
ok: [test_13] => 
  out.stdout: |-
    /105t

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```